# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I normally create a Repository directory to store all my queries for my controller. My question is, which is better to use, an eloquent model or the db:: facade?

Usually throughout my projects, I use both, but sometimes it looks messy:

```
    public function getUsersLanguagues($user_id)
    {
        $query = DB::table('languages as l')
            ->select('l.name')
            ->leftJoin('language_user as lu', 'l.id', '=', 'lu.language_id')
            ->where('lu.user_id', $user_id)
            ->get();

        return $query;
    }

    public function getUsersLanguagues($user_id)
    {
        return Languages::select('languages.name')
            ->leftJoin('language_user as lu', 'languagues.id', '=', 'lu.language_id')
            ->where('lu.user_id', $user_id)
            ->get();
    }
```

I do know they both bring back different kinds of objects,collections,etc... but i was wondering which is the best one to use, or the recommended way to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you're not really using Eloquent in either example, at least not in the way that you're trying to make them seem different. You're just using the model and then applying the query builder to the return of it's instance, anyway.

Comment: I think he needs a comparison between the Eloquent vs Query builder. In my opinion, the Eloquent ORM give you a lot of 'magic', but when there are a complicated query, e.g. full text search query, then you will need to build a query for your self. And, there are some comparisons for this regard the performance, readability, ... you should take a look at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example provided It's not seen a significant difference. In the end, you're just using the [Database's Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) and the [Eloquent's Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) which share a lot of characteristics. In fact, Eloquent injects a Database's Query Builder in a lot of its methods.

From the [Laravel 5.2 official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models):

> Think of each Eloquent model as a powerful query builder allowing you to fluently query the database table associated with the model.

---

I think one of the most significants differences between them, is the way you can bring data from relations with Eloquent:

```
# An example adapted to your needs
LanguagesUsers::where('user_id', $user_id)->first()->languages
```

The same can be accomplished in this way if you prefer:

```
# languages_users is the name you may give to your relation in your model
Languages::whereHas('languages_users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
})->get();
```

So, at least from my point of view, Eloquent is much more expresive than joining.

It's just the difference I see more significant, but there are lots of goodies Eloquent provides over the simpler Database's Query Builder. For that, I recommend you to use Eloquent whenever you can.

---

As a last commentary, notice that since laravel 5.3, the Database's [Query Builder will return collections](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/2), the same as with Eloquent. So that won't be a difference anymore.

Comment: thanks for the response, did not know on laravel 5.3, the query builder returns collections, definitely will be migrating, thanks again.